# cmd.exe - for loop and var value not changing

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, ms-dos

I'm trying to loop through music files under one directory.  Why does the FILENAME var appear to have the same value each time through the loop?  It does appear to be looping through files, however when I echo the values, FILENAME seems to remain the same as the first time through the loop.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

cd D:\Playground

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%M IN ('dir /b /s *.mp3 *.mp4 *.m4a') DO (

  set DIRNAME=%%~pM
  set DRIVELETTER=%%~dM
  set FILENAME=%%M

  set EFILENAME=%FILENAME:\=\\%
  set EDIRNAME=%DIRNAME:\=\\%

   echo "FILENAME: "
   echo %FILENAME%
   
)
```

Comment: You need to use delayedexpansion - [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this somewhere in the beginnging of the batch file:

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

Next to refeer to the filename you must use exlamation mark instead of porcentage signs.

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

cd D:\Playground

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%M IN ('dir /b /s *.mp3 *.mp4 *.m4a') DO (

  set DIRNAME=%%~pM
  set DRIVELETTER=%%~dM
  set FILENAME=%%M

  set EFILENAME=!FILENAME:\=\\!
  set EDIRNAME=!DIRNAME:\=\\!

   echo "FILENAME: "
   echo !FILENAME!
   
)
```